# Docpad paging 404 error

Tags: http-status-code-404, paging, docpad

Tell me, why has stopped working paging.
Rather, paging works, but gives 404 page.

Example: altyncev.ru/posts

[Config](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/docpad.coffee) And [posts file](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/src/documents/posts.html.eco) in my repo.

Global changes are not made.

Posts:

```
<% posts = @getCollection('posts') %>
<% for i in [@document.page.startIdx...@document.page.endIdx]: %>
    <% document = posts.at(i).toJSON() %>
    <article class="post">
        <p class="posts_date"><%= @formatDate(document.date) %></p>
        <a href="<%= document.url %>"><h3><%= document.title %></h3></a>
        <div class="post-content"><%- @getCuttedContent(String(document.contentRenderedWithoutLayouts)) %></div>
        <% if @hasReadMore(String(document.contentRenderedWithoutLayouts)): %>
        <div class="read_more"><a href="<%= document.url %>"><strong>Читать далее &rarr;</strong></a></div>
        <% end %>
    </article>
<% end %>

<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <% if !@getDocument().hasPrevPage(): %>
            <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
        <% else: %>
            <li><a href="<%= @getDocument().getPrevPage() %>">«</a></li>
        <% end %>
        <% for num in [0..@document.page.count-1]: %>
            <% if @document.page.number == num: %>
                <li class="active"><span><%= num %></span></li>
            <% else: %>
                <li><a href="<%= @getDocument().getPagedUrl(num) %>"><%= num %></a></li>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% if !@getDocument().hasNextPage(): %>
            <li class="disabled"><span>»</span></li>
        <% else: %>
            <li><a href="<%= @getDocument().getNextPage() %>">»</a></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This DocPad plugin may be a sneaky way to do it:
https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-paged